# How to launch a framework via Mesos REST API

Tags: mesos, marathon

Everyone:

I'm wondering how to launch a framework (e.g. a  docker app) via Mesos' REST API?  I just checked all the [HTTP endpoints](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/).  But I don't see anything helpful.

The reason for this question is that, I've tried [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/), which just need a Mesos master's address, and we can launch a framework over Mesos  via Marathon's REST API.
I think Marathon takes advantages over Mesos's API.  But I don't want to involve Marathon.  I want to launch a framework directly via Mesos REST API.  Could someone please help? What's the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tobi say, you can use Mesos Scheduler API to communicate with Mesos master wihtout Marathon.

You just need write a Mesos scheduler, Mesos have default docker excutor.

For your own framework, you need to Send a SUBSCRIBE json to Mesos Master to register. then, you would receive offer EVENT. user offer id, you send ACCEPT msg, you would lanch your application.

reference:

[Mesos Scheduler API](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/scheduler-http-api/)

[Mesos github example](https://github.com/apache/mesos/tree/master/src/examples)

[Rendler example](https://github.com/mesosphere/RENDLER)

Comment: Thanks, does this mean, Marathon implements its own scheduler?   And Mesos doesn't have any REST API to launch a framework, using its default scheduler?

Comment: I think if you want to use Mesos REST API, you need implement your own scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If your scheduler doesn't use the Scheduler HTTP API itself, you can't just "launch" a framework. That's not how it works.